# Hiding an Inline Model in the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to suppress displaying an inline template if no object exists to display in the inline? I'd rather hide the inline altogether than display an inline with blank/null values.

I've tried to do this two ways, first by using conditional logic to set the `model` attribute of `InlineModelAdmin` to `None` when the object itself is `None`. This doesn't work because I'm dealing with a class object in the inline definition, not instances of the class itself.

My second approach has been to modify the ModelAdmin with a similar approach. Same problem.

I haven't tried to modify the template, but it seems like that might be the best approach.

Modifying the queryset doesn't seem to work because the queryset is already returning an empty set.

Comment: Is setting `extra=0` in `InlineModelAdmin` OK for you?

Comment: @okm _facepalm_ That works great, extra=0 hides the empty inline model while allowing me to create one if I choose to. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@okm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165603/okm)

```
class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    extra = 0
```

Comment: is there any way to hide this box but not the fields? - https://i.imgur.com/minRum8.png
@okm